# How to draw circle fill with color in cocos2d-x?

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x

I am new in cocos2d-x, I am trying to draw circle with color inside it. 
I search on net and i found some code. I tried below code but it only draw circle with color border. My cocos2d-x version is 2.1.5 and I am using it for android.
I also tried to change width of border using this method : **glLineWidth(2);**    but this method is not found in my cocos2d-x. How to add color in circle and how to change width of border of circle.

```
cocos2d::ccDrawColor4B(0, 255, 255, 255);
cocos2d::ccDrawColor4F(0, 255, 255, 255);
cocos2d::ccDrawCircle( ccp(100/2, 100/2), 50, CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90), 50, false);
```

Answer (score 3):

In [CCDrawNode](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V2.2/db/df9/classcocos2d_1_1_c_c_draw_node.html) class you can draw circles, lines and polygons.

```
void drawDot(const CCPoint & pos,float  radius, const ccColor4F & color)
```

draw a fill circle at a position, with a given radius and color

Answer (score 1):

Not sure from which `cocos2d-x` version is available, but you should have a specific method for drawing solid circles.-

```
void drawSolidCircle( const Point& center, float radius, float angle, unsigned int segments, float scaleX, float scaleY);
```

Have a look to the nightly [CCDrawingPrimitives.cpp](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/develop/cocos2dx/draw_nodes/CCDrawingPrimitives.cpp) class.

Comment: Thank you for ans but this method is in 3.0alpha0-pre

Comment: Well, you could try and copy the method. The main difference should be calling `glDrawArrays` with `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN` instead of `GL_LINE_STRIP`

Answer (score 1):

Just add a new method in CCDrawingPrimitives.  It is identical to `ccDrawCircle` except the `glDrawArrays` uses `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN` instead of `GL_LINE_STRIP`

In the header, add:

```
 void CC_DLL ccDrawSolidCircle( const CCPoint& center, float radius, float angle, unsigned int segments, bool drawLineToCenter);
```

In the .cpp file, add:

```
 void ccDrawSolidCircle( const CCPoint& center, float radius, float angle, unsigned int segments, bool drawLineToCenter)
 {
lazy_init();

float scaleX = 1;
float scaleY = 1;

int additionalSegment = 1;
if (drawLineToCenter)
    additionalSegment++;

const float coef = 2.0f * (float)M_PI/segments;

GLfloat *vertices = (GLfloat*)calloc( sizeof(GLfloat)*2*(segments+2), 1);
if( ! vertices )
    return;

for(unsigned int i = 0;i <= segments; i++) {
    float rads = i*coef;
    GLfloat j = radius * cosf(rads + angle) * scaleX + center.x;
    GLfloat k = radius * sinf(rads + angle) * scaleY + center.y;

    vertices[i*2] = j;
    vertices[i*2+1] = k;
}
vertices[(segments+1)*2] = center.x;
vertices[(segments+1)*2+1] = center.y;

s_pShader->use();
s_pShader->setUniformsForBuiltins();
s_pShader->setUniformLocationWith4fv(s_nColorLocation, (GLfloat*) &s_tColor.r, 1);

ccGLEnableVertexAttribs( kCCVertexAttribFlag_Position );

 #ifdef EMSCRIPTEN
setGLBufferData(vertices, sizeof(GLfloat)*2*(segments+2));
glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_Position, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
 #else
glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_Position, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vertices);
 #endif // EMSCRIPTEN
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, (GLsizei) segments+additionalSegment);

free( vertices );

CC_INCREMENT_GL_DRAWS(1);
 }
```